# Reading last Row in Excel while importing - SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, excel, import

> i have the following code that imports Excel Data to a table and updates some parameters , however i am unable to read all the rows , only the last row is being read , i want to be able to read all the rows and update their values in the table

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR select  Barcode,MSISDN,POS,[SIM Card Number],[Date of Sale] FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel     12.0;Database=C:\ActivatedCards.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT Barcode,MSISDN,POS,[SIM Card     Number],[Date of Sale] FROM [sheet1$]')
declare @Barcode as bigint
declare @MSISDN as bigint
declare @POS as nvarchar(50)
declare @SIMCardNb as bigint
declare @ActivatedDate as date

begin

open c 

fetch next from c into @Barcode,@MSISDN,@POS,@SIMCardNb,@ActivatedDate


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
select @Barcode=Barcode,@MSISDN=MSISDN,@POS=POS,@SIMCardNb=[SIM Card     Number],@ActivatedDate=[Date of Sale] FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel  12.0;Database=C:\ActivatedCards.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT Barcode,MSISDN,POS,[SIM Card  Number],[Date of Sale] FROM [sheet1$]')
where Barcode <> ''

Update Cards 
set 
MSISDN=@MSISDN ,
POSSold=@POS,
Activated=1,
SIMCardNb=@SIMCardNb,
ActivatedDate=@ActivatedDate,
ImportDate=GETDATE(),
CollectionDeadlineDate=DateAdd(Day,30,ImportDate)
where Cards.BarCode=@Barcode


fetch next from c into @Barcode,@MSISDN,@POS,@SIMCardNb,@ActivatedDate
end 


CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NPOI api to  read/write xls, doc, ppt files. microsoft Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' built in api is not good for this task.

easy to use and very productive example can be found following under.

http://npoi.codeplex.com/